# Flex: Disable Zip Code validation for Non US or Canada

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

Currently I am setting ZipCode domain based on country dropdown value.

```
if(this.countryCTComboBox.getSelectedCode() == 'USA')
                {
                    this.zipCodeTextInputFieldValidator.domain = ZipCodeValidatorDomainType.US_ONLY;
                    this.zipCodeTextInputFieldValidator.wrongLengthError = this.zipCodeTextInputFieldValidator.wrongUSFormatError;
                } 
                else if(this.countryCTComboBox.getSelectedCode() == 'Canada')
                {
                    this.zipCodeTextInputFieldValidator.domain = ZipCodeValidatorDomainType.CANADA_ONLY
                    this.zipCodeTextInputFieldValidator.wrongLengthError = this.zipCodeTextInputFieldValidator.wrongCAFormatError;
                }
```

It works fine if USA or Canada is selected from the country dropdown. But It gives `wrongUSFormat` error for all other countries.

IS there any way to disable the validation any other country is selected.

Answer (score 1):

That last part of this statement would be to run a different validator or no validator at all on the string entered into the if statement.

```
} else {
    trace("this is not a US or Canada Zip code");
    // do something else with the zip code now, or do nothing
    zipCodeTextInputFieldValidator.source = null;
}
```

You probably need to modify the other branches of this `if/else` statement so that they re-enable the validator by setting the `source` to the appropriate text input.

I'm not sure what else you need to do, but also check to make certain you haven't restricted your text field to all numbers or a certain length of characters which could trip you up.

Comment: In the code I posted I am setting the domain for ZipCode. Not sure If you are aware of flex's ZipCode component. In else statement I want to disable Zipcodevalidator completely but problem is how to do it.

Comment: @HimanshuYadav, you haven't showed how you hook up the validator, but you obviously need to just un-hook it. For example, you could set the validator's `source` property to null: `zipCodeTextInputFieldValidator.source = null;` I guess I'll add this to the answer ;)